# Ошибка 61 CMAKE на QtCreator в windows

Tags: c++, windows, qtcreator, cmake

Для QtCreator поставил CMAKE. В конце создания нового C++ проекта (не Qt) на последнем шаге просят запустить CMAKE. Жму и получаю ошибку в логе:

> -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
>   -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
>   -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/gcc.exe
>   -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/gcc.exe -- broken CMake Error at C:/Program Files (x86)/CMake/share/cmake-3.6/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:61
>   (message):   The C compiler "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/gcc.exe" is
>   not able to compile   a simple test program.
>
> It fails with the following output:
>
> Change Dir:
>   C:/Users/Admin/Documents/QT/build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-РџРѕ
>   СѓРјРѕР»С‡Р°РЅРёСЋ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
>   "cmTC_fdb2d/fast"
>
> C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
>   CMakeFiles\cmTC_fdb2d.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_fdb2d.dir/build
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory
>   'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/QT/build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-По
>   умолчанию/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_fdb2d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>
> C:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\gcc.exe -o
>   CMakeFiles\cmTC_fdb2d.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c
>   "C:\Users\Admin\Documents\QT\build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-РџРѕ
>   СѓРјРѕР»С‡Р°РЅРёСЋ\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
>
> gcc.exe: error:
>   C:\Users\Admin\Documents\QT\build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-РџРѕ
>   СѓРјРѕР»С‡Р°РЅРёСЋ\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c: No such file
>   or   directory
>
> gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> CMakeFiles\cmTC_fdb2d.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_fdb2d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_fdb2d.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj]   Error 1
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory
>   'C:/Users/Admin/Documents/QT/build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-По
>   умолчанию/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> makefile:125: recipe for target 'cmTC_fdb2d/fast' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_fdb2d/fast] Error 2
>
> CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project. Call
>   Stack (most recent call first):   CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)
>
> -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/QT/build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-РџРѕ
>   СѓРјРѕР»С‡Р°РЅРёСЋ/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also
>   "C:/Users/Admin/Documents/QT/build-untitled6-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MinGW_32bit-РџРѕ
>   СѓРјРѕР»С‡Р°РЅРёСЋ/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Из строки:

```
cmake:61 (message): The C compiler "C:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/gcc.exe" is not able to compile a simple test program.
```

понимаю что компилятор не смог откомпилировать тестовый СИ исходник в сгенерированном проекте системой CMAKE. C MS компилятором то же самое.

Как быть?

Comment: cmake это не сборщик, это генератор проектов. У Вас какие-то проблемы с путями — уберите русский язык из путей

Comment: Уже. А собрать и сгенерировать проект это разные вещи?

Comment: Конечно. CMake генерирует проектные файлы, которые в дальнейшем используются уже конкретной системой сборки, которая и будет собирать проект. В Вашем случае, судя по всему, генерируются make файлы.

Comment: @ixSci, я вчера помедитировал немного над этим вопросом, правильней ее называть строитель ну или как то так. На английском она имеет категорию build system.

Comment: Хорошо, я удалил комментарии. Мне показалось, что Вы меня пытаетесь убедить в том, что это таки система сборки.

Comment: взаимно. все поправил. просто в различных статьях написано система сборки вот и прицепилось на язык. а по большому счеты вы правы cmake генерирует файлы проектов.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел причину. CMAKE не понимает кирилицу в путях из за проблем windows кодировки.

Comment: cmake то ее понимает, то просто винда не может ее в консоли правильно отдать - там до сих пор три кодировки.

Comment: @KoVadim, поправил и вопрос и ответ. хотя можно было вопрос удалить. но по этому вопросу в сети ни у кого не было правильного ответа. пусть полежит на SO