# Ошибка создания проекта в Qt Creator с использованием CMake (Windows)

Tags: c++, qtcreator, cmake

уважаемы форумчане!

У меня возникла проблема при создании проекта в Qt Creator с использованием утилиты cmake на Windows.

Изначально был установлен Qt Creator с  компилятором MinGW 4.9.2. 
К нему в дополнение устанавливается система сборки CMake 3.12.2 x86, до этого CMake никогда установлен не был.
При создании проекта с помощью qmake никаких проблем не возникает, а вот с CMake они есть. Так вышло, что сейчас острая нужда использовать именно CMake, и никак иначе.

Собственно проблема: при создании проекта CMake начинает тестирование компиляторов, прохождение которого заканчивается ошибкой на этапе создания файла testCCompiler.c в директории C:\Users\Имя Пользователя\AppData...\CMakeTmp. Он не создается, компилятор его не находит, не компилирует и тест проваливается.
Error log и Output log прилагаю.

Error log:

> Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:
>   Change Dir: C:/Users/Брылкин
>   Дмитрий/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-thZtlk/qtc-cmake-ZpzDAurJ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp
>
> Run Build Command:"D:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe"
>   "cmTC_26fb2/fast" D:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/mingw32-make.exe -f
>   CMakeFiles\cmTC_26fb2.dir\build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_26fb2.dir/build
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/┴Ё√ыъшэ
>   ─ьшЄЁшщ/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-thZtlk/qtc-cmake-ZpzDAurJ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_26fb2.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj
>
> D:\Qt\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\gcc.exe    -o
>   CMakeFiles\cmTC_26fb2.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj   -c
>   "C:\Users\╨С╤А╤Л╨╗╨║╨╕╨╜
>   ╨Ф╨╝╨╕╤В╤А╨╕╨╣\AppData\Local\Temp\QtCreator-thZtlk\qtc-cmake-ZpzDAurJ\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
>
> gcc.exe: error: C:\Users\╨С╤А╤Л╨╗╨║╨╕╨╜
>   ╨Ф╨╝╨╕╤В╤А╨╕╨╣\AppData\Local\Temp\QtCreator-thZtlk\qtc-cmake-ZpzDAurJ\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c:
>   No such file or directory
>
> gcc.exe: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.
>
> CMakeFiles\cmTC_26fb2.dir\build.make:64: recipe for target
>   'CMakeFiles/cmTC_26fb2.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/cmTC_26fb2.dir/testCCompiler.c.obj] Error 1
>
> mingw32-make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/┴Ё√ыъшэ
>   ─ьшЄЁшщ/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-thZtlk/qtc-cmake-ZpzDAurJ/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
>
> makefile:120: recipe for target 'cmTC_26fb2/fast' failed
>
> mingw32-make.exe: *** [cmTC_26fb2/fast] Error 2

Output log:

> The system is: Windows - 6.1.7601 - AMD64 Compiling the C compiler
>   identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded. Compiler:
>   D:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/gcc.exe  Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 0
>
> Compilation of the C compiler identification source
>   "CMakeCCompilerId.c" produced "a.exe"
>
> The C compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/Users/Брылкин
>   Дмитрий/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-thZtlk/qtc-cmake-ZpzDAurJ/CMakeFiles/3.12.2/CompilerIdC/a.exe"
>
> Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded. Compiler:
>   D:/Qt/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/g++.exe  Build flags:  Id flags:
>
> The output was: 0
>
> Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source
>   "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.exe"
>
> The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/Users/Брылкин
>   Дмитрий/AppData/Local/Temp/QtCreator-thZtlk/qtc-cmake-ZpzDAurJ/CMakeFiles/3.12.2/CompilerIdCXX/a.exe"

Скрин с описанием элементов комплекта также прилагаю (вдруг пригодится).
[image]

Если кто знает как решить эту проблему, буду очень благодарен за помощь.

Сам я грешу на русские символы, которые стоят вместо \Имя Пользователя\ в пути к тестовому файлу. Но как решить эту проблему пока не знаю.

Comment: Собственно вот ответ, почему не работает. Действительно, проблема в русских символах в пути, но как изменить стандартный путь для тестов cmake пока остается не ясным.
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/571913/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-61-cmake-%D0%BD%D0%B0-qtcreator-%D0%B2-windows?rq=1

Comment: Не используйте неанглийские буквы и пробелы в путях. Это общий совет для всего, что связано с программированием — это позволит избежать многих проблем.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я уже решил проблему изменением имени папки пользователя. Тему можно закрывать.